# Webpack proper bootstrap loading with extract-text-webpack-plugin

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I am trying to bundle css files with webpack extract-text-webpack-plugin it works great with local files that are int (projects)/src/assets/styles, but I also need bootstrap.css from node_modules and if I try adding it to import b from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'; the plugin just throws an error that sounds something like this "bootstrap.css Unexpected token (7:5) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type." If I add '!style!css!' as described in this question
 [Webpack Error while including bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812752/webpack-error-while-including-bootstrap-3) it does work, but now it is injected in index.html  which may slowdown the overall app. So how do you correctly load the bootstrap style from node_modules? I tried copying it with copy-webpack-plugin, but the copying is performed after the loaders have done their job. so any suggestions?

Comment: And add this if the bootstrap is loaded into the head it overrides any files that appear above such as <head><link href='custom.css'><style>{injected style}</style></head>

Answer (score 0):

With a bit more research and debuging the problem was in css loader path, which was pointed to the app source directory, that is why it could not access the node_modules.